# $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$ in a $M_n(R)$ when $R$ is a semiring?

Tags: matrices, semiring

Let $R$ be a unitary commutative semi-ring and let $M_n(R)$ be the semi-ring of $n \times n$ matrices with coefficients in $R$.  Let's call $I$ the identity matrix in $M_n(R)$ (it exists because $R$ is unitary).

> Is it true that for any $A$ and $B$ in $M_n(R)$ such that $AB=I$ we have $BA=I$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is proven in [Inversion of Matrices over a Commutative Semiring](http://lacim.uqam.ca/~christo/Publi%C3%A9s/1984/Inversion.pdf) by Reutenauer and Straubing.
The proofs aren't especially short though (as you request in the comments).
The first two paragraphs give good context for their paper though:

> It is a well-known consequence of the elementary theory of vector spaces
>   that if $A$ and $B$ are $n$-by-$n$ matrices over a field (or even a skew field) such
>   that $AB = 1$, then $BA = 1$. This result remains true for matrices over a
>   commutative ring, however, it is not, in general, true for matrices over noncommutative
>   rings.
>
> In this paper we show that if $A$ and $B$ are $n$-by-$n$ matrices over a
>   commutative semiring, then the equation $AB = 1$ implies $BA = 1$. We give
>   two proofs: one algebraic in nature, the other more combinatorial. Both
>   proofs use a generalization of the familiar product law for determinants over
>   a commutative semiring.

It's worth mentioning that "semi-ring" for them requires having a multiplicative identity, so they do prove the result you desire.

Comment: Thank you very much for this  answer! I should have mention it in the main post, but my principal motivation was to avoid rings such that I cannot use determinant and see if it is still true, and your answer also give an answer to this motivation : as a generalization of determinant seems to be required in "Both proves".

Comment: @jcdornano If you don't want to use rings (to the degree that determinants are undefined), then how would you expect matrix multiplication to be defined?

Comment: @Arthur : Matrix multiplication over a semi-ring works the usual way, but determinant cannot be defined for any matrix  when the underlying additive monoïde of the ring is not a group

Comment: @jcdornano I forgot the minus sign in the determinant definition, you're right.