# Let R be a commutative ring. Then AB=1 implies BA=1 in $M_n(R)$. Looking for a noncalculation proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking to prove the above statement, if R is commutative then AB=1 in $M_n(R)$ implies BA=1, except without using brute force calculation. I was thinking about using some homomorphism, like left or right multiplication on a matrix by A. Can someone please provide guidance?

Comment: Guidance would be to search for your question by putting your title into the search bar. This is a frequently asked question.  I don’t think anyone tries to do it by brute force…

Comment: the supposed duplicate doesn't specify, but the answers assume there they're talking about linear algebra, ie assuming $R$ is a _field_. is there a duplicate of this actual question out there?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870770/ab-i-implies-ba-i-in-a-m-nr-when-r-is-a-semiring) shows it for unitary commutative semirings.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've added the more accurate duplicate as well.  Anyhow, as long as $R$ is commutative, this should be easily dispatched using the determinant, which I thought was the approach used by the linear algebra versions. e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3800863/29335. I guess I overestimated how well-known that argument was.

Comment: The goal of associating a duplicate, as I understand it, is that it has an answer that addresses the question at a reasonably similar (but not necessarily identical) question.